# Two way to write an answer

Tags: meaning

When I receive an agreement I need to approve and send it back. In this case wpıld it be correct if I write the sentences below as explanation.

> 1)I sent you the agreement approved ,back.

> 2)I sent you the agreement back with our approval.

I thought second one also means that somoene approved of me sending the mail then I sent it.

Comment: Why would it need an "explanation"?  The person presumably knows that the agreement has been sent back, and that it has been approved.  Either way I don't see why anything needs to be said.  If I'm wrong then "I approved the agreement and sent it back" seems far clearer, You use that kind of wording in the question. I wonder why you don't use it as explanation.

Comment: I just wondered if these sentences are grammatically correct and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is fine.

The first doesn't work well.  The phrasal verb "send back" can be separated

> I sent the approved agreement back.

Or even with two objects:

> I sent you the approved agreement back.

But now the word "back" is losing contact with the first part of the verb, so it is already hard to understand. It violates the "end weight" principal of "longer, weightier phrases at the end of a sentence"

You shouldn't put the adjective "approved" after the noun it modifies, in most cases. So "approved agreement" not "agreement approved".

But actually it is easier to describe the two actions in two clauses

> I approved the agreement and sent it back.

(Present perfect would also be a good choice here: "I've approved...."

Comment: Thank you so much . If I say I sent the agreement approved by my boss, should use “that is” after agreement or it can be understood without “that is”?